# Is there a way to move batch data into a datastream?

Tags: apache-flink

I was looking at the Table-API. Can you transform a batch dataset to a table and then use the todatastream function to convert to a datastream? 
I know there was a similar question a while back and the answer was no. Has this changed since the rewrite of the Table API?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible yet. Table API (and SQL) queries are translated either to DataSet API or DataStream API programs depending on the type of their sources.

However, there are plans for a unified batch/stream API on the lower level.